# Get list of All products and transfer to different store

Tags: magento-1.9, module, configurable-product, associate-products, admin-controller

I want to get a list of all the products in my Magento stores. the problem is configurable and grouped products. i want to transfer products to another server with external framework, i want to get configurable and grouped products with their associated simple products as a field.

Comment: you should use some collection staff - then you can filter products collection in order to get what you need. Please prepare more information - where do you want to get it? Into to external file and then send it or just send it from the code?

Comment: @lord_of_strings in controller of my module i want to create a `json` text and send it to another server .

Comment: than maybe before putting data into json you should filter it as I said and then send it (it's REST Api I think)

Answer (score 0):

```
$client = new SoapClient('https://www.yourstoreURL.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');


$session = $client->login('xml/soap username', 'xml/soap password');

$complexFilter = array(
    'complex_filter' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'type',
            'value' => array('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'configurable')
        )
    )
);
$result = $client->catalogProductList($session, $complexFilter);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are advised against, please provide a small explanation along with your piece of code.